# linked list destructor with std::move c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, destructor, stdmove

I'm learning data structures in C++;

I've written a destructor for a linked list as follows:

```
    ~List(){
        Node* temporary = new Node;
        Node* node = head;
        while(node != nullptr){
            temporary = node;
            node = node->next;
            delete temporary;
        }
    }
```

But then I realized that I can do:

```
        ~List(){
        Node* node = head;
        while(node != nullptr){
            node = std::move(node->next);
        }
    }
```

Avoiding creating a temporary object, I tried it and worked fine, but I don't know if it is okay, I didn't find a destructor like this in any other place.

Comment: `std::move` on a pointer has no effect whatsoever. It is clear you misunderstand something about the object model in C++, but I'm not sure what that misunderstanding is. Can you clarify why you think the move would substitute the `delete`? In the second example, the node are leaked. It is also odd to `new` an object in a destructor.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how objects in C++ work. This is not Java, I would recommend a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). `std::move` does not call `delete`.

Comment: If you are learning data structures, the first thing to learn (IMHO) is that a "linked list" is just about the *worst* data structure you can use. But if you want to insist on terrible, then at least don't code it yourself, use `std::list`.

Comment: @François Andrieux Doesn´t std::move delete the pointer after the the call?

Comment: You've managed to introduce - and leak - a dynamic allocation in the destructor. Definitely second the suggestion to read a good book.

Comment: `Node* temporary = new Node;` So in order to demolish a row of houses, you go and build a new house first? I don't think a demolition business that does this will survive for long.

Comment: @EricCardozo No, it does not. Pointers are a trivial fundamental type and moving them is the same as copying them. A pointer just a hold a value which says "which object". It is not the object it points to. You may be familiar with high level languages like Java or C# where variables are typically references to an instance which manage lifetime, but that isn't how pointers work in C++.

Comment: "Doesn´t std::move delete the pointer after the the call?" - No. `std::move` is nothing but a cast to rvalue reference. It doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: moving _can_ be destructive, but that's only if you're using owning smart pointers or other non-trivial types (and it happens when you _use_ the rvalue reference in a move ctor or assignment, not when you do the cast)

Comment: @Jesper Juhl So everyone should drop ther CS majors and give up programming cause everything is made up alredy, I should look for a job selling cars instead. Why bother to learn c++? If I can do it easier in python?

Comment: @EricCardozo Do what you please. But I'd still advice against linked lists. Besides, university doesn't really produce that great real-life programmers - you always have to re-train them.

Comment: There's no harm in rewriting existing containers for learning IMO, but so far the lesson is just that you don't understand pointers yet.

Comment: fwiw with `std::unique_ptr<Node>` your code would work.

Comment: *"I realized that I can do: [code] Avoiding creating a temporary object,"* -- an easier way to avoid creating a "temporary" object is to not create it. (If you remove the `= new Node` from your first code block, you avoid creating the unnecessary object without impacting anything else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::move` doesn't do anything by it's own, it only cast something to rvalue.

How the rvalue is used is determined by the function that accept it, and assignment of raw pointer does nothing different than copy in that case.

But for example, if you're using `std::unique_ptr`, the [`operator=(unique_ptr&&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) **would** delete the original data after assignment*.

---

so if you're using something like

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Node{
   std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
   // possibly move List destructor here
   // i.e. destruct a Node would safely remove all sub-node non-recursively
};

struct List{
   std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
   // write destructor to prevent deep recursion
   ~List(){
      while(head) head = std::move(head->next); // current head is deleted after assignment
   }
};
```

then it would work

---

<sup>*btw, self-assignment is safe because it's actually effectively `reset(r.release())`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
~List(){
    Node* temporary = new Node;
    Node* node = head;
    while(node != nullptr){
        temporary = node;
        node = node->next;
        delete temporary;
    }
}
```

produces a memory leak due to this unneeded memory allocation

```
    Node* temporary = new Node;
```

In this code snippet

```
    ~List(){
    Node* node = head;
    while(node != nullptr){
        node = std::move(node->next);
    }
}
```

neither memory is freed. Only the pointer `node` is reassigned until it will be equal to a null pointer. So there are again numerous memory leaks.

If you do not want to use an intermediate variable then the destructor can be written for example the following way

```
    #include <functional>

    //...

    ~List(){
        while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the manual memory management rather than smart pointers?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Where do you have found smart pointers in the original question? It is obvious that the author of the question learns how to manage memory with new and delete.

Comment: And have the Node destructor delete next? if you've decided to implement a singly-linked list, I'm not sure that recursive destructors are an improvement.

Comment: @Useless There are no recursive destructions. There is used a while loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl there are few data structure ideas worse than that of a linked list. One of them is a linked list with smart pointers.

Comment: There are no recursive destructions _because_ you're not using Node-owning smart pointers.